# How to set email message body in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the code below in `class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base` to send an email:

```
mail :to => "email@address", :subject => "Subject"
```

How do I add the message body?

Comment: Couldn't find it in the doc?

Comment: ...specifically, [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#create-a-mailer-view)

Comment: thanks @PinnyM - a lot more helpful than the previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the mailer view of same action for email body. If your mailer action is `send_mail` then your default mail body must be `view/users/send_mail.html.erb`
For detail see the following link,
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#create-a-mailer-view